# How to increase the number of polygons while maintaining mesh curvature in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices, edges

I have a need to increase the number of polygons in this mesh, maintaining mesh curvature:
[image]

I tried increasing the number of polygons with the *Subdivide* tool in edit mode, with this result:
[image]

The problem is that the points added with the subdivision, do not maintain the same curvature of the mesh, but were created in a straight line between one existing mesh point and another:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case a *Subdivide* operation with the *Smoothness* at 1 should give the desired result, but for more complicated shapes, don't use the *Subdivide* tool in *Edit* mode, it will tend to flatten the faces as you show, instead give a *Subdivision Surface* to your object and apply it, contrary to the simple *Subdivide* operation, the modifier will better interpolate the roundness on the whole shape.